# How to set a breakpoint when a method is called using LLDB on OS X?

Tags: debuggers, osx, lldb

I'm trying to hit a breakpoint that I set in LLDB (CLI), but for whatever reason I'm not hitting my breakpoint.  I am messing around with the stock Calculator.app on OS X, and am trying to call / hit my breakpoint when I open the About dialog box of the Calculator.app.

I launch the Calculator.app, then I start lldb from a Terminal window.  I find the process of the Calculator.app using ps and grep.  I attach to the running process using LLDB.  I then issue the `continue` command in LLDB to allow the Calculator.app to continue running.

Then I set a breakpoint in LLDB when the following method is called, `showAbout`

I type the following command into LLDB,
`(lldb) breakpoint set --method showAbout`

However when I click `About Calculator` from the menu bar it doesn't halt the program, but rather shows the About dialog box for the Calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Calculator app is stripped as can be seen by running `nm`.
You will need to find the address of the method using `class-dump`:

```
$ class-dump -A /Applications/Calculator.app | grep showAbout
- (void)showAbout:(id)arg1; // IMP=0x0000000100009939
```

However as the Calculator application is already running, the address has been slided because of ASLR.
To find the ASLR slide you can use my tool called [get_aslr](https://github.com/Tyilo/get_aslr), like so:

```
$ sudo get_aslr $(pgrep Calculator)
ASLR slide: 0x9508000
```

You then add the two numbers together:

```
0x0000000100009939 + 0x9508000 = 0x109511939
```

That is the current address of the `showAbout:` method.
Now you just need to set the breakpoint in `lldb`:

```
b *0x109511939
```

And it works!

Comment: You don't need `get_aslr`; you can also find the address the binary is loaded at by running `image list` from within lldb.